# Speed up evaluation of simple polynomial expression in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, svg, bezier

I've written a rather large Python program to do some analysis of data given in the form of a list of cubic Bezier splines.  It's very slow and, much to my surprise, after profiling I found that most of the time is spent in the following quite simple function.

```
    def point(P0,P1,P2,P3,t):
        return ((1-t)**3 * P0) + \
               (3 * (1-t)**2 * t * P1) + \
               (3 * (1-t) * t**2 * P2) + \
               (t**3 * P3)
```

where t is a float and P0, P1, P2, and P3 are complex numbers.

Attempting to decrease the number of times this function is executed would, I worry, cause me a lot of headache and might reduce accuracy of my results, so before I try that I'm wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to speed this up.

I've heard I might be able to compile this as a C/C++ function that could be called from my python code, but I've never done something like that (and it's been a long time since I used C/C++ for anything) so I wanted to get an expert opinion before spending time diving into anything like that.

Also, to be thorough, the above function is really a method of the Path class in a module called svg.path.  Its exact syntax is as follows.

```
    def point(self, pos):
        """Calculate the x,y position at a certain position of the path"""
        return ((1-pos) ** 3 * self.start) + \
               (3 * (1-pos) ** 2 * pos * self.control1) + \
               (3 * (1-pos) * pos ** 2 * self.control2) + \
               (pos ** 3 * self.end)
```

Comment: Before even considering writing a C extension, I'd a) try memoizing that function and if that doesn't help b) see if you can rewrite the loopy parts into some `numpy` matrix manipulation.

Comment: The [official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) says to try to avoid using backslashes for line continuation. In this case, you can wrap the `return`ed expression in parentheses.

Comment: Maybe changing `**` to a plain `*` will improve the performance. Python's power calculation is much more slower than multiply. It is the most simple and straightforward way to speed up for your problem.

Comment: You can get rid of `**` in favor of `*`and factor the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `**` by `*` and factor the polynomial like:

```
def point(P0, P1, P2, P3, t):
    return P0 + \ 
        t * (3 * (P1 - P0) + \
        t * (3 * (P0 + P2) - 6 * P1 + \
        t * (-P0 + 3 * (P1 - P2) + P3)))
```

You gain nearly a factor 2 in performance.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know the concept as an name :-)

Comment: Thanks Vivian (and @HerringtonDarkholme)!  I can't say I have any idea why this is faster (the * vs. ** part that is), but you're right!

Comment: The different operations have different costs: sums are cheap multiplications are more expensive and power are very expensive the original expression have 3 power and 8 multiplication this one have only 7 multiplication.